# Appcelerator and iOS7 - Error with iPhone 5s

Tags: ios7, titanium, appcelerator, xcode5.0.1

my iOS app i ready for sending to App Store; everything works well but if I testing my app from Xcode choosing iPhone retina - 4-inch 64-bit I receive this message in a red screen from simulator:

**- Could not find file app.js.**

This happen only with iPhone 5s simulator; have you any suggestions?

PS I read another similar cases relative app that dont work on iPhone 5s only.

Answer (score 0):

When you switch between simulators run `alloy compile --config platform=ios && titanium build -p ios` to make sure that everything is properly build. Check more in [Alloy Debugging and Troubleshooting Documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Debugging_and_Troubleshooting-section-34637808_AlloyDebuggingandTroubleshooting-%5BERROR%5DNoapp.jsfound.Ensuretheapp.jsfileexistsinyourproject%27sResourcesdirectory.).